# want to terminate threadpool once variable reaches certain value

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_THREAD_COUNT 50

class A
{
public:
    static void ExecDecrementX(void* thisObj, int *x)
    {
        cout << "DecrementX thread..." << endl;
        A *obj = (A*)thisObj;
        obj->DecrementX(x);
    }

    void DecrementX(int* x)
    {
        cout << "Thread Instantiated........" << endl;
        for (; *x <= 1200; (*x)++)
        {
            cout << "DecrementX thread, X = " << *x << endl;
            if (*x == 1100)
            {
                HANDLE hEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, false, L"MyEvent1");
                if (!hEvent) { return; }
                ResetEvent(hEvent);
                if (SetEvent(hEvent))
                {
                    cout << "Got The signal - MyEvent 1......." << endl;
                    CloseHandle(hEvent);
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "End of the Thread ......" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int x = 1000;
    A* obj1 = new A();
    DWORD dwRet;
    HANDLE Events_Handle[1];
    HANDLE  hEvent1 = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, L"MyEvent1");
    if (!hEvent1) return -1;
    Events_Handle[0] = hEvent1;
    void(*fPtr)(void*, int*) = A::ExecDecrementX;
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::thread_group ThreadPool;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(ioService);
    for (int threadcount = 0; threadcount < MAX_THREAD_COUNT; threadcount++)
    {
        ThreadPool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
    }
    cout << "Main thread\n";
    ioService.post(boost::bind(fPtr, obj1, &x));
    while (1)
    {
        dwRet = WaitForMultipleObjects(1, Events_Handle, false, INFINITE);
        cout << "dwRet = " << dwRet << endl;
        if (dwRet == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            cout << "All events were signaled..." << endl;
            ioService.stop();
            ThreadPool.interrupt_all();
            cout << "Remaining threads interrupted... X = " << x << endl;
            CloseHandle(hEvent1);
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Main Thread: At the End X = " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My requirment is once x reaches 1100, interrupted all threads but even after interruption of threadpool I see threadpool goes on and keep printing till end.
Could you please help me understanding what is happening and how can I resolve it?

THanks,
JK

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could hardly be more confused with all the threading primitives you throw around.

Firstly you mix no less than 3 different levels of threading abstractions:

- Asio asynchronous task queueing
- Boost thread portable thread library ( thread_group and interruption points)
- Windows native API (`WaitForMultipleObjects`, Events)

Even so, you get most of it... mixed up:

- The Event is a named object. That is, it's intended for interprocess synchronization (IPC) and all the instances are different kernel handles for the very same synchronization object...
- You use `WaitForMultipleObjects` to wait for... 1 fixed synchronization object. Seems you can do better :)
- The use of `interrupt_all()` implies that you use interruption points, *yet* you never handle the `thread_interrupted` exception? See the docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption)
- You seem to use Boost Asio with the intention of servicing tasks on a thread pool. **Yet** you only ever post 1 task to the service, meaning that no more than 1 of the threads will ever be involved in running the task.

  > The key source of confusion here seems to be that a *task* is **not** a *thread*.
  >
  > The pool manages the *threads*, the service juggles *tasks*. Your 'task' appears to have the ambition to occupy a full thread. This is never a good fit for a thread pool (the whole idea is to reuse the same threads for multiple *short-lived* tasks) and Asynchronous processing in particular (the long-running task blocks the queue and nothing asynchronous will happen on the same thread).
- The use of `work` is misguided. The lifetime of it is not managed to end before the join, meaning that the `io_service::run` operations will never return. See [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html):

  > The work class is used to inform the `io_service` when work starts and finishes. This ensures that the `io_service` object's `run()` function **will not exit** while work is underway, and that it does exit when there is no unfinished work remaining.
- Finally, why on earth would you need 50 threads in an Asio task queue. That only makes sense if you have very long running tasks that are **not** CPU bound. That's the very opposite of asynchronous task processing.
- Ironically, `DecrementX` seems to do nothing else but *increment* x. Which should have been accessed under a mutex. I made it an `atomic_size_t` below

Here's a humble attempt at cleaning up:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1d24e356680a417)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class A {
    boost::atomic_size_t x { 0 };
    boost::asio::io_service& _svc;

public:
    A(boost::asio::io_service& svc) : _svc(svc) {}
    void IncrementX() {
        std::cout << "IncrementX X = " << x << "\n";
        if (x++ == 1100)
            _svc.stop();
    }

    size_t getX() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;

    asio::io_service ioService;
    A obj(ioService);

    thread_group pool;
    optional<asio::io_service::work> work = asio::io_service::work(ioService);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++) {
        pool.create_thread(bind(&asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
    }

    std::cout << "Main thread\n";

    while (!ioService.stopped())
    {
        ioService.post(bind(&A::IncrementX, &obj));
    }

    work.reset();
    pool.join_all();

    std::cout << "Main Thread: At the End X = " << obj.getX() << std::endl;
}
```

Prints (cut-down):

```
Main thread
IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 00

IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 2
2
IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 4
4
IncrementX X = 5
IncrementX X = 7IncrementX X = 
7
IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 99

IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 1111

IncrementX X = 13
IncrementX X = 14
IncrementX X = 15
IncrementX X = 16
IncrementX X = 17
IncrementX X = 18
IncrementX X = 19
IncrementX X = 20
IncrementX X = 21
...
...
IncrementX X = 1078IncrementX X = 
1074
IncrementX X = 1079
IncrementX X = 
IncrementX X = IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 1082
10751081

IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 10851085

IncrementX X = 10811085IncrementX X = 
1087IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 1088
IncrementX X = 1089
IncrementX X = 1090
IncrementX X = 1091

IncrementX X = 1092
IncrementX X = 1093

1087IncrementX X = 
1095IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 1096

1097
IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 1097
1100
IncrementX X = IncrementX X = 11021102



IncrementX X = 1075

Main Thread: At the End X = 1108

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.006s
```

Comment: If  you want you view the recorded livestream of me refactoring this answer [here around the 18'45'' mark](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/qihold-butchering-a-thread-fest-question/). In particular you can see I replaced the even with a `boost::condition_variable`/`mutex`/`unique_lock` combo first and handled the `thread_interrupted` exception (although my final code doesn't contain any of those, you might still want to see?)